# Proof of logical equivalence with raa

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

I need to solve the following logical equivalence:   (p ↔  q) ↔ ((p∧q)∨(¬p∧¬q))

I know i need to solve the problem in 2 parts, and i think i can do it with raa but im stuck. So  if someone could give me some help it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume $P \iff Q$. We know $P \vee \neg P$ by Law of Excluded Middle. If $P$, then we get $Q$ as they are equivalent, so we get $P \wedge Q$ and thus $(P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg P)$. If $\neg P$, then follow the same argument.

Now assume $(P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg P)$. I will show that $P \wedge Q$ leads to $P \iff Q$, as the other case uses this case. Since we have both $P$ and $Q$, we know by material conditional properties on the antecedent and conditional that $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$ (if something is true, $\textit{anything}$ leads to it). Do the same for the other case.